# Create Temporary Table mysql from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried to make temporary tables on mysql via PHP, but after I open in the browser it looks empty, please help, thank's a lot

```
include "conn.php";

$maketemp = "
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table_1 (
        `idarea` int NOT NULL,
        `kode` varchar(20),
        PRIMARY KEY(idarea) 
    )
"; 
mysql_query($maketemp, $connect) or die ("Sql error : ".mysql_error());

$inserttemp = "
    INSERT INTO temp_table_1 (`idarea`, `kode`)
    SELECT `id_areasf`, `kd_areasf` FROM `areasf`
";
mysql_query($inserttemp, $connect) or die ("Sql error : ".mysql_error());

$select = "SELECT * FROM temp_table_1";
$export = mysql_query($select, $connect) or die ("Sql error : ".mysql_error());
```

Comment: What gets returned from the mysql_query calls?  and does you SQL work fine manually?

Comment: Exactly. Temporary tables are dropped after you finished your connection (session) in browser (e.g. close tab/browser)

Comment: don't use mysql(deprecated in PHP 5.5.0 and removed in php 7.0.0), use mysqli or PDO

Comment: Empty as in a blank screen? That could be a suppressed fatal error causing a 500 response. Be sure to enable display of all errors for debugging.

Comment: Well I would get away from using `mysql_` as its been removed as of PHP7.

Comment: Unless it runs into an error, this script doesn’t produce any output to begin with … so what exactly are you expecting to see in your browser?